# how to write float numbers to serial port

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I want to send a float number to serial port. I wrote this code:

```
import serial
import time
import struct

my_float = 125.568
my_data = struct.pack('f',my_float)
n=ser.write(my_data)
# print(ser.write() + " Bytes successfully written")
print(n,"Bytes successfully written")
```

Is that right?

Comment: We're not able to answer this question: it depends entirely on what is on the other end of the connection. You're packing the float into a binary representation here, but what if the thing on the other ends wants a simple ASCII string? Or JSON? Or something else?

Comment: what's the issue?